plant context from root doesn't have connected geometry query port
I'm sure that I'm doing something simple wrong.
I'm trying to get started using DirectTranscription() with my robot; my code roughly looks like:
builder = DiagramBuilder()
    plant: MultibodyPlant
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(
        builder, time_step=0.001)
    parser = Parser(plant)
    parser.AddModels("robot.sdf") 
    plant.SetUseSampledOutputPorts(False) # gets rid of intermediate abstract state in discrete-time plant
    plant.Finalize()

    diagram = builder.Build()

    # follow query object input port connection advice from: https://drake.mit.edu/troubleshooting.html
    plant_context = plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(root_context=diagram.CreateDefaultContext())

    dirtran = DirectTranscription(plant, plant_context, num_time_samples= 21, input_port_index = plant.get_actuation_input_port().get_index())
    prog = dirtran.prog()
    prog.AddLinearEqualityConstraint(dirtran.initial_state(), plant.GetPositionsAndVelocities(plant_context))
    Solve(prog)

I'm getting this error on the line Solve(prog)
The provided context doesn't show a connection for the plant's query input port (see MultibodyPlant::get_geometry_query_input_port()). See https://drake.mit.edu/troubleshooting.html#mbp-unconnected-query-object-port for help.'

I'm exporting my Diagram to SVG, and i can see that the geometry query input port is connected in the SVG (image is in the following link: SVG of Diagram)
As far as I understand, I've replicated the example in the link exactly. What am I doing wrong?

You need to pass in the diagram to DirectTranscription, not the plant by itself. This plant needs the SceneGraph in order to evaluate it's dynamics.
But this is also a bit of a warning flag. If you have contact dynamics in your plant, and you are trying to optimize through them, then this is not a problem that DirectTranscription will solve well. For that, you would need to think about planning through contact.

Thanks for the quick reply! Is there a way to fix contacts (and certain degrees of freedom at a contact) in a MultibodyPlant? I'm interested in planning the trajectory in between contacts here.

Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318267/ask-the-user-to-create-a-new-question-after-being-asked-in-comments.  Don't use comments to ask new questions -- post new questions by themselves, as new topics.
